# Unable to connect to Azure Service fabric cluster from MAC

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-cli

I am trying to connect to a secured Azure Service Fabric cluster from my MAC but I am having some SSL issues

I can authenticate the /Explorer through the same certificate via web browser but when I am trying the same with my command-line I am getting SSl errors.
Any suggestions please ?

```html
Ushas-MacBook-Pro:azure-16 ushasm$ sfctl cluster select --endpoint https://mylinuxx.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com:19080 --pem client.pem
```

Error :

> Error occurred in request., SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mylinuxx.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com',
>   port=19080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),)) Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 601, in urlopen
>       chunked=chunked)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 346, in _make_request
>       self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 850, in _validate_conn
>       conn.connect()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line
>   326, in connect
>       ssl_context=context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line
>   329, in ssl_wrap_socket
>       return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
>   line 407, in wrap_socket
>       _context=self, _session=session)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
>   line 814, in **init**
>       self.do_handshake()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
>   line 1068, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
>   line 689, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line
>   440, in send
>       timeout=timeout   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 668, in urlopen
>       **response_kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 668, in urlopen
>       **response_kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 668, in urlopen
>       **response_kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 639, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line
>   388, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mylinuxx.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com',
>   port=19080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/service_client.py",
>   line 201, in send
>       **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   508, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   618, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line
>   506, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mylinuxx.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com',
>   port=19080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 125, in
>   invoke
>       cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/invocation.py", line 85,
>   in execute
>       cmd_result = parsed_args.func(params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line 67,
>   in **call**
>       return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line 123,
>   in _command_handler
>       result = op(client, **command_args) if client else op(**command_args)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sfctl/custom_cluster.py", line
>   95, in select
>       rest_client.send(rest_client.get('/')).raise_for_status()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/service_client.py",
>   line 227, in send
>       raise_with_traceback(ClientRequestError, msg, err)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/exceptions.py", line
>   45, in raise_with_traceback
>       raise error.with_traceback(exc_traceback)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/service_client.py",
>   line 201, in send
>       **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   508, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
>   618, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line
>   506, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request) msrest.exceptions.ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request.,
>   SSLError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mylinuxx.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com',
>   port=19080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a self-signed certificate? If so, add `--no-verify` to the `sfctl cluster select` command.

> If it is a self-signed certificate that is not CA signed, you can pass
>   the --no-verify option to bypass CA verification If it is a
>   self-signed certificate that is not CA signed, you can pass the
>   --no-verify option to bypass CA verification

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cli)

Comment: Tried both the options but still no luck :(